# bind9 conditional forwarding not working as expected

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-hosting

Need your experience advice, We have a BIND9 DNS server that operates both privately and publicly for the domain xyz.com. I use the private DNS for certain secure nodes on our local network. I want all VPN users to be able to resolve these secure nodes using our local DNS, which is functioning correctly. However, the issue arises when a VPN user queries an A record that is public. For example, if "secure.xyz.com" has a local entry in the zone file, it works as expected. However, when the entry is not present, I expect BIND to conditionally forward the query to a remote DNS server and resolve it for the VPN client. Unfortunately, this is not happening. BIND only searches for entries that are available in the local zone file and then times out.
Here are my configuration files.

Options File

> ```
> options {
>          directory "/var/cache/bind";
>          recursion yes;                   // Enable DNS recursion
>          allow-recursion { localhost; }; // Allow recursion only for localhost
>          allow-transfer { none; };       // Disable zone transfers by default
>          allow-query { any; };           // Allow queries from any IP address
>          // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
>          // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
>          // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113
>
>          // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
>          // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
>          // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
>          // the all-0's placeholder.
>
>          forwarders {
>               8.8.8.8;
>          };
>
>          //========================================================================
>          // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
>          // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
>          //========================================================================
>          dnssec-validation auto;
>
>          listen-on-v6 { any; };
>  };
> ```

name.config.local

> ```
>   zone "xyz.com" {
>       type master;
>       file "/etc/bind/db.xyz.com";
>       forwarders {
>           8.8.8.8;
>           8.8.4.4;                    // Additional forwarder (optional)
>       };
>   };
> ```

db.xyz.com

```
; BIND reverse data file for empty rfc1918 zone
;
; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is used for multiple zones.
; Instead, copy it, edit named.conf, and use that copy.
;
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                          86400 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
            IN      A       x.x.x.x
@           IN      NS      localhost.
ftp         IN      A       x.x.x.x
www         IN      A       x.x.x.x
new         IN      A       x.x.x.x
4k          IN      A       x.x.x.x
jpdate      IN      A       x.x.x.x
record1    IN      A       x.x.x.x
record2    IN      A       x.x.x.x
record2    IN      A       x.x.x.x
```

Regards,
Yousuf

Answer (score 0):

What you have configured is not conditional forward. Conditional forward is where you specify a domain and then it's dns server like this

```
options {
            directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };

        querylog yes;


        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

    zone "windows.net" {
            type forward;
            forwarders { 168.63.129.16; };
    };
```

Comment: Thank you Guido for the update  I put a couple of forwarders. I am aware of this setting.  how can I manage Bind to forward the query to public DNS if A record is not found in the local zone file?